# Producer-consumer blocking queue with consumer filtering

Tags: java, producer-consumer, blockingqueue

I'm trying to write a producer-consumer pattern in java. I'm a network client connected to many servers over a series of different connections. The servers produce varying 'work' packets that all get put into one blocking queue. What I'm trying to do is block my consumers in a way that only specific types of work packets get delivered to specific consumers.

Example:

- The blocking queue is filled with three different types of work packet objects: A, B, C
- Two consumers are waiting for work packet objects. Consumer 1 only wants type A and consumer 2 only wants type B or C

Is there some standard class in java.util... or do I have to roll my own class? Also, whats the best way to do roll my own if needed?

Thanks in advance!

Andrew Klofas

Comment: You need something between your blocking queue and your consumers that "routes" the packets to the correct consumers.  Alternatively, you can give each consumer its own blocking queue, and fill the queues based on packet type.

Comment: Why use one blocking queue?  Or is there an indeterminable number of 'types of work'?

Comment: There is an indeterminate number of types. What I want to do is have a few specialized consumers that respond to specific work types, then a catch-all consumer.

Comment: this sounds more like publish-subscribe

Comment: With this design, you run the risk of filling the queue if you have a message type X that nobody wants to consume.

Comment: @maasg That's a good point. Maybe having the consumer allocate a local blocking queue and registering it with the producer thread. That would be more of a publish subscribe pattern and wouldn't have the risk of overflowing the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a standard way to do this in java.util, but here's a simple design:

I'm assuming A,B,C all implement interface D and that it doesn't matter if an A is processed out-of-order with the Bs and Cs.

Have a single "input" BlockingQueue with a set of sorting consumers. These consumers determine the type of the objects in the queue and feeds them into separate type-specific "output" queues that your real workers take from. Is there some constraint that requires you only have one queue?

Answer (score 2):

You can get this behavior with standard JMS. Your producer creates messages that are placed on the JMS topic. Consumers subscribe to the topic using a filtered subscription: That way, subscriber X only gets type X messages. (More about subscription on the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/TopicSession.html) )

A durable subscriber will get your requirement of queueing messages per subscriber covered.

This is a pub/sub model.